# Docker: capstone fails on installation

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
#20 64.75     Complete output (5 lines):
#20 64.75     running install
#20 64.75     running build
#20 64.75     Building C extensions
#20 64.75     ./make.sh: line 118: make: command not found
#20 64.75     error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'libcapstone.so.4'
```

(I installed capstone on mac with brew)

Comment: Can you try to install `make` to your environment?

Comment: @OguzhanAygun yes,  make + build-essential

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added make, build-essential and this solved my problem.